# VBA Regex pattern to match keywords and their occurrences in all paragraphs only after the ":"

Tags: excel, regex, vba

Consider a VBA string created from an array, joined by vbCr.

```
str = "eager beaver:some are eager to meet me today. They won't be eager tomorrow, but grim in 
      their faces." & vbCr _
      "grim ogre:meet me at the grim dine bar tonight. I love to enjoy good food." & vbCr _
      "play & enjoy:there are some people who lead a joyous life."

ar = array("meet","grim","eager","enjoy","some")
```

for e.g., the below regex pattern selects all occurrences of all the keywords in each line, but also matches the keywords "eager", "grim" and "enjoy" found before the ":".

```
Regex.Pattern = "\b(meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)\b"  '.Pattern = "\b(" & Join(ar, "|") & ")\b"
```

Here is the regex pattern:

https://regex101.com/r/jHZJXV/1

`I only need a Regex pattern` that excludes matching keywords found before the ":" i.e. the `FirstIndex of any keyword match should start after the ":"`. Also a keyword can occur multiple times in any line.

**EDIT:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()
Dim Str As String, sJoined As String
Dim matches As Object
Dim regex As Object
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Ar

Str = "eager beaver:some are eager to meet me today. They won't be eager tomorrow, but grim in their faces." & vbCr _
      & "grim ogre:meet me at the grim dine bar tonight. I love to enjoy good food." & vbCr _
      & "play & enjoy:there are some people who lead a joyous life."

Debug.Print Str

Ar = Array("meet", "grim", "eager", "enjoy", "some")
sJoined = "" & Join(Ar, ")|(") & ""
Debug.Print sJoined
Stop

Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regex
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "(?:" & sJoined & ")(?!.*:)"

    Debug.Print .Pattern
    
    If .test(Str) Then
        Set matches = .Execute(Str)
        Stop
        
        For i = 0 To (matches.Count - 1)
            For j = 0 To (matches(i).submatches.Count - 1)
                
                Debug.Print matches(i), matches(i).submatches(j), matches(i).firstindex, matches(i).Length
                Stop
            
            Next j
'            Debug.Print matches(i), matches(i).firstindex, matches(i).Length
        Next i
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

The above code shows only 1 match and also returns only 1 submatches (all 3 lines) as shown in the below picture. There are no matched keywords returned as submatches along with their matched lines - which is what i would like it to return.

[image]

**EDIT:**
@Ron Rosenfeld this is the output (9 matches) i am expecting without splitting the keywords array or the String. The FirstIndex should be a running index.

```
eager beaver: some           13            4 
eager beaver: eager          22            5 
eager beaver: meet           31            4 
eager beaver: eager          60            5 
eager beaver: grim           80            4 
grim ogre:    meet          110            4 
grim ogre:    grim          125            4 
grim ogre:    enjoy         158            5 
play & enjoy: some          197            4
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You could first get the text after the first occurrence of `:` with `^[^:]*:(.+)` see https://regex101.com/r/QvKsCA/1  and then run your regex on the capture group 1 value

Comment: @Thefourthbird Interesting. Can you explain your pattern? And what did you mean by `run your regex on the capture group 1 value`? Is it possible to do that using VBA Regex?

Comment: Not sure about the syntax, but this `^` is the start of the string, this `[^:]*` matches optional chars other than `:` and then you match the first `:` This part `(.+)` captures 1 or more chars in group 1. The group 1 value is what you are interested in, and over that match you can run your pattern with the alternations. Another idea is to split on the first occurrence of `:` or split on `:` and then glue the parts except for the first part together.

Comment: I edited my original post for you. As you can see, submatch (only 1 count) is returning 1st line after `:` and then entire 2nd and 3rd line completely. See `FirstIndex` shows as 0 i.e. its still matching from first character and `Length` returned is 234 which means all 3 lines are being returned. I think what you meant by group is to return each line after `:`. So there would have been multiple match or submatch counts, but it seem it is not returning correctly in VBA. What i would like it to return as submatches is the keyword and its matched line (matching happening only after `:`).

Comment: What is the expected output for the text at the regex101 link?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what @the fourth bird shared, only seems to work in regex101 and not with any of the concatenated keywords. What i would ideally like to see in regex101 is to see the keywords matches highlighted only after the `:` in each line i.e. any words before the `:`, matching one or more of the keywords, should be excluded from highlighting.

Comment: @sifar Try it without matching newlines to match a single line `^[^:\r\n]*:(.+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew will it try to match all the above given keywords across each of the lines? `(meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)`

Comment: Yes, what you need cannot be done with regex alone in VBA

Comment: `(?:meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)(?!.*:)` will match all the keywords only after the `:` in Regex 101.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Assuming VBA supports assertions, you should post your answer. https://regex101.com/r/wU16wH/1

Comment: @sln Yes, I just need to figure out how to implement in in VBA before posting an answer. BTW, VBA supports look-ahead but not look-behind.

Comment: Note that `(?:meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)(?!.*:)` does not guarantee that there actually is a `:`

Comment: @Thefourthbird That's more easily implemented in the string testing portion of the code. However, the OP did not indicate what he might want to do in that circumstance, and the code *"excludes matching keywords found before the `:`"*. If there's no colon, nothing would get excluded.

Comment: there will always be a ":" in my data as its a concatenation between 2 dimensions of a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want for output. Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()
Dim Str As String
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim match As match
Dim regex As RegExp
Dim i As Long, j As Long, s As Variant, v As Variant
Dim keyAr, strAr
Dim lFI As Long

Str = "eager beaver:some are eager to meet me today. They won't be eager tomorrow, but grim in their faces." & vbCr _
      & "grim ogre:meet me at the grim dine bar tonight. I love to enjoy good food." & vbCr _
      & "play & enjoy:there are some people who lead a joyous life."
      
keyAr = Array("meet", "grim", "some", "eager", "enjoy")
strAr = Split(Str, vbCr)


Set regex = New RegExp
With regex
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "(?:\b" & Join(keyAr, "|") & ")\b(?!.*:)"
    lFI = 0
    For Each s In strAr
        If .Test(s) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(s)
            For Each match In matches
                Debug.Print Left(s, InStr(s, ":")), match.Value, match.FirstIndex + lFI, match.Length
            Next match
        End If
    lFI = lFI + Len(s)
    Next s
End With
End Sub
```

***Output***
*This matches your output.
Howver, the "First Index" is not the true one as, in your example, you are omitting the CR at the end of each line.
If you want the real First Index, add one(1) when `lFI` is incremented*

```
eager beaver: some           13            4 
eager beaver: eager          22            5 
eager beaver: meet           31            4 
eager beaver: eager          60            5 
eager beaver: grim           80            4 
grim ogre:    meet           110           4 
grim ogre:    grim           125           4 
grim ogre:    enjoy          158           5 
play & enjoy: some           197           4
```

*Formal explanation of derived regex*

### (?:meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)(?!.*:)

```
(?:meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)(?!.*:)
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)`

  - [Match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `meet`

    - [Match the character string “meet” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `meet`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `grim`

    - [Match the character string “grim” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `grim`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `eager`

    - [Match the character string “eager” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `eager`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `enjoy`

    - [Match the character string “enjoy” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `enjoy`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `some`

    - [Match the character string “some” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `some`
- [Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*:)`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the colon character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `:`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: the only difference is in implementation. As you can see, I am not splitting the Str, but want to run it on entire string and get the same matches that you are getting (as shown above). The thing is to get the above same output without splitting keywords array or looping keywords. Thats what i am trying to achieve and thats why i needed a regex pattern that could work on the entire string and not on a splitted array via loops. Also, the `FirstIndex` will not be as above for each line. It will be a running index over the entire string.

Comment: See my edits showing new code and the expected `Output`. The code though gives me all matches (11) instead of needed 9.

Comment: @sifar The code is not looping keywords. It is looping sentences. Could easily be altered to provide running first index. The reason I have 10 matches is because I added one to a line so as to test for multiple identical matches in same line. Will post that variation in a few hours. Not sure about modifying it to not split the lines, however. The result should be the same.

Comment: @sifar code edited to provide same output as you show in your example. Still have to loop through each sentence individually, but the result is the same. Not looping keywords.

Comment: Thanks. However, is it not possible to avoid splitting the Str also, as shown in my code and execute regex pattern on entire Str to find all these matches? This is what is my intent. If not, i am glad to mark your solution as the answer.

Comment: @sifar I have not been able to produce a regex that will work in vba to provide the output you show without checking each line individually. Note that the output you show is not showing a true `FirstIndex`. Also, I suspect processing each line individually will be faster, even if I could produce a regex that would work on the entire phrase.

Comment: I meant firstindex as the true  positions of each matches found in the entire String, which will definitely start from 0.

Comment: @sifar And I meant that what you wrote does not represent that as it does not include the <linefeed> character at the end of each string. Any FirstIndex after the first line will be off by the number of lines processed compared with what you are showing. I believe you can see that at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/wU16wH/1)

Comment: Hi @ron rosenfeld would you be kind enough to explain the pattern `(?:meet|grim|eager|enjoy|some)(?!.*:)` for my understanding? and is the `(?:` necessary?

Comment: @sifar I have edited my answer to include a formal explanation. But basically, it looks for any of the keywords and ensures that there is no colon `:` following that word. `(?:...` makes this a non-capturing group, which makes both the regex and the associated VBA code simpler, since you don't have to look at submatches.